# Alter a object within a object within a loop

Tags: php, laravel

My aim is to add a edit a object within another object.

Within the code below you can see two database where one has been into the value of another (collection1 into collection), this works fine as all data was added. With the last section of code you can see me trying to add a new value to the allSub value within the collection object. This is where the issue lies as there is data being added but its showing the highest level id. For example; the event_type_id should be 1 to 15, the test as shown shows the correct the number (within the upper level) but the allSub value shares the same number, 15.

I need this to show the correct relating id as I'm going to pass it to a function.

```
$collection = DB::table('event_types')->get();

$collection1 = DB::table('event_types_sub')->get();


foreach ($collection as $key => $value) {

  $collection[$key]->allSub = $collection1;

}

 foreach ($collection as $key1 => $value1) {

   $collection[$key1]->test = $value1->event_type_id;

   foreach ($value1->allSub as $key2 => $value2) {

     $collection[$key1]->allSub[$key2]->check = $value1->event_type_id;

   }

 }
```

- laravel map returns the same result

Answer (score 0):

I've simplified your code:

```
$types = DB::table('event_types')->get();
$subs = DB::table('event_types_sub')->get();

foreach ($types as $type) {
    $type->subs = $subs;
    $type->test = $type->event_type_id;

    foreach ($type->subs as $sub) {
        $sub->check = $type->event_type_id;
    }
}
```

Since you are working with objects they are always passed by reference, not copied. So in every iteration in the `$types` loop you are overriding the `check` property on the same collection of `$subs`. The last iteration is with the id of 15 so the one and only collection of `$subs` is overridden to have `check = 15`. To achieve what you are trying to do you would have to do a deep copy of this collection. But if you get to that point that probably means you are doing something wrong, and there is a better way to solve your problem.

Another thing you can do is to convert both collections to arrays and then `$subs` will be copied for every `$type`:

```
$types = DB::table('event_types')->get()->toArray();
$subs = DB::table('event_types_sub')->get()->toArray();

foreach ($types as &$type) { // must use reference (&)
    $type['subs'] = $subs; // $subs array is copied
    $type['test'] = $type['event_type_id'];

    foreach ($type['subs'] as &$sub) { // must use reference (&)
        $sub['check'] = $type['event_type_id'];
    }
}
```

Then you have the `$types` array which should have the data you need. Again, there is probably a more elegant solution than this.

Comment: Thanks, what would be the elegant way of getting this solved? What would be the better way to solve this without a deep copy?

Comment: Convert it to an array and you will get what you wanted but it will be an array instead of an object. I can't know what is a better solution without the function that you are passing this data to.